# Scroll to top of page after async post back

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asynchronous, code-behind

So I need to scroll to the top of the page after an async post back in an asp.net update panel.

The code I used was this:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestEventHandler);
function EndRequestEventHandler(sender, args)
{
    scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

However, I only want this to be run when I click on a certain button which causes the async postback.

How do I wire this event up in my code behind button event?

Any help would be appreacited, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void myButon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(MyControl), "someText", "alert('!');", true); 
}
```

Comment: I've tried this without success. Something is making the page scroll down again to the panel I just activated.

Answer (score 4):

My quest for a solution is finally over. This question was part of the help, and the rest I found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/54fd8987-525b-4ae1-8b78-1b0c7bd03d56).

Had to override ASP.NET Ajax's behaviour of memorizing the scroll position:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 

manager.add_beginRequest(beginRequest); 
function beginRequest() 
{ 
    manager._scrollPosition = null; 
} 
</script>
```

And then use the bit of code in the answer here, on the codebehind of the page I wanted to scroll to the top:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(MyControl), "someText", "window.scrollTo(0, 0)", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

I used Farinha's answer (thanks!) and changed it slightly so I could just call the method any place I wanted to scroll to the top, but maintain the scroll position otherwise.

```
public static void ScrollToTop(int intPosY = 0)
    {
        string strScript = @"var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
            manager.add_beginRequest(beginRequest); 
            function beginRequest() 
            { 
                manager._scrollPosition = null; 
            }
            window.scroll(0," + intPosY.ToString() + ");";

        Page pagCurrent = GetCurrentPage();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pagCurrent, pagCurrent.GetType(), string.Empty, strScript, true);

        return;
    }

public static Page GetCurrentPage()
{
    return (HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving on the answers of [@Farinha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5584378/177710) and [@Bradford Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583655/177710), the code can be simplified to this:

```
var script = 
    "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._scrollPosition = null; " +
    "window.scrollTo(0, 0);"

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "key", script, true);
```

I'm actually not even sure why their scripts work since they add the reset of the `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager`'s `_scrollPosition` as an `add_beginRequest` handler, and here we are actually returning from the request.

Anyway, resetting the `_scrollPosition` right before making your own `scrollTo()` call definitely works.